# Some questions on a paper of Wilking

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I am currently trying to understand Wilking's paper ["A Lie algebraic approach to Ricci flow invariant curvature conditions and Harnack inequalities"](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3065160) (DOI: [10.1515/crelle.2012.018](https://doi.org/10.1515/crelle.2012.018), [arXiv:1011.3561](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3561)). If I may, I wish to clarify a few points where I am getting stuck:

1. I am not sure how to prove Lemma 2.3. Wilking says that one can use estimates similar to Shi for linearized equations built from the PDE satisfied by $S_k - Hk$, where $Hk$ is a Harnack operator, and $S_k$ is an approximation as $k \to \infty$. Is this straightforward? Also, it is not at all clear to me why the sequence $S_k$ needs to be introduced at all for proving Theorem 2.1.
2. On page 234, Wilking takes a closed convex set $C$ of maximal dimension inside the vector space $S^2_B(\mathfrak{g})$, and defines the **cone at infinity** as $$\partial_\infty C := \lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\frac{C}{\lambda}.$$
   I am having trouble understanding exactly what this notation means.

Any help will be highly appreaciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, this is just the Gromov-Hausdorff limit of $C$ with the metric rescaled by $1/\lambda,$ where $\lambda \to \infty.$ In a metric sense, $C$ is "asymptotic" to $\partial_{\infty}C.$